# Silverlight Scrollbar value doesn't become minimum when scrolled back

Tags: c#, silverlight, scrollbar

I am finding it difficult to understanding why my silverlight scrollbar is not becoming the minimum value when scrolled back once it is moved forward.

I have set the minimum value as 1 and maximum value to 1500 dynamically through binding.

When i scroll forward, the value reaches up to 1500. But when scrolled back, the value doesn't reach 1 but sometimes the end is reached when the value is still 7 or 10.

```
<ScrollBar x:Name="MyScBar" Maximum="{Binding Maximum,Mode=TwoWay}" Minimum="1" 
           Orientation="Horizontal" Value="{Binding SValue,Mode=TwoWay}" 
           Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  IsEnabled="True">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="ValueChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding ScrollValueChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ScrollBar>
```

Can any one help me here?

Comment: Is this because, the older value is what i am getting? If so, how can i get the new value in my MVVM implementation?

Comment: Might not make a difference, but if you are getting the old value then try adding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged to your binding.